# Method within a class won't take away value from integer argument

Tags: c#

I've currently only been learning C# for a week so apologies for any stupid errors but I'm trying to call a method within a switch statement to take away an integer value that is declared within a list from the argument given to the method, the argument in this case is the health of the currEnemy object, but when the currEnemy.health value is printed out to the console it's value is unchanged and I can't figure out why.

The list that stores the integer value that the currEnemy.health is taken away by a long with the health variable which is set to an integer value in the Enemy class:

```
public List<Weapon> myWepList = new List<Weapon>(){
    new Weapon {name = "Dagger", dmg = 10, stamDrain = 5},
    new Weapon {name = "Sword", dmg = 20, stamDrain = 20},
    new Weapon {name = "Halberd", dmg = 40, stamDrain = 20}
};

public int health{ get; set; }
```

The method within the player class that should take away the 'dmg' value from the enemy.health value and set enemy.health to a new value:

```
public void charAttack(int enemyHealth)
{
    enemyHealth -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

Then the code that calls the above method to display the currEnemy.health's new value:

```
enum PlayerInput
{
    Attack,
    Block,
}

while (gameStart == true) //this part onwards is stored in the main method
{
    string playerInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    PlayerInput inputChoice;

    Console.WriteLine("Type 'attack' to attack the enemy");

    if (Enum.TryParse<PlayerInput>(playerInput, true, out inputChoice))
    {
        switch (inputChoice)
        {
            case PlayerInput.Attack:
                currPlayer.charAttack(currEnemy.health);
                Console.WriteLine("Enemy Health is {0}", currEnemy.health);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I'd also appreciate if any general advice is just given to me about my code considering I'm completely new to C# so any constructive advice would be great, thank you.

Comment: Read that : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html Then read it again, then read it a final time, then check your code :)

Comment: @CyrilGandon I will do, thanks :)

Comment: It was like a down vote party in here for anyone who suggested `ref`.  Neat. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method:

```
public void charAttack(int enemyHealth)
{
    enemyHealth -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

... is basically pointless. The statement `enemyHealth -= ...` only affects the *parameter* called `enemyHealth`. It won't change `currEnemy.Health` at all - because the method argument is passed by value. In other words, the process is:

- `currEnemy.health` is evaluated
- The value is used as the initial value for `enemyHealth`
- The method executes
- The final value of `enemyHealth` isn't used at all

See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

There are various ways you could tackle this - for example, you might want:

```
currPlayer.Attack(currEnemy);
```

where the `Attack` method would look something like:

```
public void Attack(Enemy enemy)
{
    Weapon weapon = equippedWep[0];
    enemy.Health -= weapon.Damage;
}
```

Note that the last line is very different to your previous code, because it would *set* the value of `enemy.Health` afterwards... you wouldn't just be changing a parameter, but the state of an object.

Comment: Ahhhh this worked thank you! thanks for your explanation too I now realize were the silly error I made was

Answer (score 3):

You can't change a value that is passing to a function. It is the same in all langages, not only C#.

```
int a = 0;

function changeA(int a)
{
    a = 1;
}

print a; // show 0, not 1
```

You can change a value that is contained into an object:

```
public class Obj
{
    public int health{ get; set; }
}

var o = new Obj();
function changeHealth(Obj o)
{
    o.health = 1;
}

print o.health; // show 1
```

C# or whatever, that is the first thing you need to understand.

For your actual problem, here is a proposal: pass the actual object representing the enemy, not just his health. Then deduce the health of the enemy object.

```
public void charAttack(Player enemy)
{
    enemy.health -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}

while (gameStart == true) //this part onwards is stored in the main method
{
    string playerInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    PlayerInput inputChoice;

    Console.WriteLine("Type 'attack' to attack the enemy");

    if (Enum.TryParse<PlayerInput>(playerInput, true, out inputChoice))
    {
        switch (inputChoice)
        {
            case PlayerInput.Attack:
                currPlayer.charAttack(currEnemy);
                Console.WriteLine("Enemy Health is {0}", currEnemy.health);
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# passes ints by value which means that you only get a copy of the value in the method. To solve it you can parse the enemy object instead like this:

```
public void charAttack(Enemy enemy)
{
    enemy.health -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

This would affect the health on the enemy object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `charAttack` method declaration.  The `enemyHealth` parameter is not being passed *by reference*, so you are actually modifying a *copy* of the variable not the original (this is call passing *by value*).

You can either pass the parameter *by reference*, which will mean that you modify the original:

```
public void charAttack(ref int enemyHealth)
{
    enemyHealth -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

Or you could return the modified result and set your original value to it:

```
public int charAttack()
{
    return equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
i = charAttack();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your enemyHealth value by reference. C# defaults to passing by value which means the method gets it own copy of the value. To pass the actual int object pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void charAttack(int enemyHealth)
{
    enemyHealth -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

Based on the above method, the behavior you're experiencing is expected.  You are not actually stating "change the calling `currEnemy.health`" when calling this method, but change `enemyHealth`.  The problem is `currEnemy.health` is being passed by value (as in the literal value is passed, not the "object" that represents that value) not by reference.

There are two (or more) ways to fix this:

one would be use a ref to the enemy health:

```
public void charAttack(ref int enemyHealth)
{
    enemyHealth -= equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

and call your method like:

```
currPlayer.charAttack(ref currEnemy.health);
```

or return a new enemy health from your method:

```
public int charAttack(int enemyHealth)
{
    return enemyHealth - equippedWep[0].dmg;
}
```

and call like:

```
currEnemy.heatlh =  currPlayer.charAttack(currEnemy.health);
```